# Looking for desktop program to find images on my local hard drive similar to a sample image

Tags: search

I know this question has been asked before (many years ago), and there have seen suggestions for programs, but some don't exist anymore and none of them seem to do what I want to do. Octagon doesn't seem to work. VisiPics searches for any and all duplicates. What I want to do is point the program at a sample image, then have it search through my hard drive and find *similar* images to that image. Maybe a different size, or a slightly different crop, or a slightly different color balance, or maybe even a slightly different (but still quite similar) view of the same subject. I've found several programs that attempt to search the entire drive for similar/duplicate images. On a large drive with lots of images this takes forever and the matches aren't flexible enough. So I'm basically looking for a local version of Tineye or Google Image search that's smart enough to find similar (but non identical) images on my hard drive.

I have an image which is small and possibly slightly cropped from a much larger image.  I'm pretty sure the larger image is somewhere on a 1TB drive, but as yet I have not been able to find it. Is there now a tool that can help me? I don't really care how long it takes to do the search.

Comment: There is another Stack Exchange site that is all about [softwarerecs.se]. Try searching them for questions about [`local image search`](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=Local+image+search). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but nothing usable there either.  There are lots of programs that will will find ALLl near duplicates (NxN match) on a disk or directory, but as far as I can tell none that will find near duplicates of a single file (1xN) match to the contents of a disk or directory. Seems like it would be a much easier task, but I can't find any software that does it. Seems like such an obviously useful tool I'm surprised it doesn't seem to exist.